# How to install my application on mobile

Tags: android

I want to directly install my application after dowloading it from android market place 
is it possible ?

and i also want to know about How android market install Update version of product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to do anything for installation, when you download any application from android market then it will take care about installation.

Regarding update version, if android market found any update version for any installed application inside the phone, then it will notify you regarding the updated version. For the same you dont need to do anything, you just have to click update in android market, thats it, it will automatically update/install the application.

Comment: Is it possible to know how many users using my application?

Comment: @nileshbirhade if you have registered with and published application in android market then i think there is a dashboard by which you can come to know how many active install, total installs are there currently.

Comment: I would suggest you to go through this: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Answer (score 0):

Downloading any application from market means that you're automatically installing it.

Updates appear for user when he visits Market and as developer you only upload update in your publishing panel. The update simply overwrites the application on the phone but keeps the user data.